# Expand a large dataframe with keping two variables the same and every possible combination with third

Tags: r

I am new to R and have researched a lot in stack overflow but am still not able to resolve my issue. I need to expand my dataset which has 4 variables:

```
date          kid  kid2  sums  
01/01/2012    A    12    123    
01/10/2012    A    15    100    
01/03/2012    B    10    900   
01/01/2012    C    10    100
```

Desired output : I have expanded till 01/10/2012:

```
date    kid kid2    sums    
1/1/2012    A   12  123 
1/2/2012    A   12  0   *
1/3/2012    A   12  0   *
1/4/2012    A   12  0   *
1/5/2012    A   12  0   *
1/6/2012    A   12  0   *
1/7/2012    A   12  0   *
1/8/2012    A   12  0   *
1/9/2012    A   12  0   *
1/10/2012   A   15  100 
1/1/2012    B   10  900 
1/2/2012    B   10  0   *
1/3/2012    B   10  900 
1/4/2012    B   10  0   *
1/5/2012    B   10  0   *
1/6/2012    B   10  0   *
1/7/2012    B   10  0   *
1/8/2012    B   10  0   *
1/9/2012    B   10  0   *
1/10/2012   B   10  0   *
1/1/2012    C   10  100 
1/2/2012    C   10  0   *
1/3/2012    C   10  0   *
1/4/2012    C   10  0   *
1/5/2012    C   10  0   *
1/6/2012    C   10  0   *
1/7/2012    C   10  0   *
1/8/2012    C   10  0   *
1/9/2012    C   10  0   *
1/10/2012   C   10  0   *
```

I need to expand in such a way that for every given combination of `kid` and `kid2` in the data I need to spread the data across all dates in Jan 2012 and for the new rows added assign sums as O.

My dataset is huge with millions of rows so I am looking for a optimal and efficient way.

I am looking at using expand/grid but I am not sure how to keep the (`kid` and `kid2`) combination as from data and then spread across all missing dates.

Appreciate your help.

SJ

Comment: Have you looked at `expand.grid`?

Comment: Hi.. I did look at it but how do I get two arguments;; One with all possible combination of dates and second with all given combination of kid and kid2 (A,12), (B,10) and (C,15). And then add wherever dates are missing in data. Sorry I am new to R and can't figure it..

Comment: What's with the '1/10/2012   A   15  100 ' line. Should that be '1/10/2012   A   12  100 ' ?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. It should be '1/10/2012 A 12 100'.. Thanks for pointing it out and sorry for confusion..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. First lest's read your data:

```
df <- read.table(text="date          kid  kid2  sums  
01/01/2012    A    12    123    
01/10/2012    A    15    100    
01/03/2012    B    10    900   
01/01/2012    C    10    100", header=TRUE)
```

Then convert the date into `Date` format:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now I will create a vector with all dates that you need, from january 1 to 31.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date("01/31/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"), by="day")
```

With that we can create a new `data.frame` with all combinations of the dates and kids:

```
df2<-merge(dates, df[,c(-1, -4)], by=NULL)
names(df2)[1] <- "date"
```

To get the original sums back, we can merge them, but keeping all results, and reordering to get it into the order you want:

```
df3<-merge(df, df2, all=TRUE)
df3<-df3[order(df3$kid,df3$kid2, df3$date), ]
```

And, finally, if you want, you can replace `NA`'s with `0`'s:

```
df3<-replace(df3, is.na(df3), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. Though I have one followup question, so my data size is getting way too big and R is crashing as my original data has 150K combination of Unique id which I want to spread across 2 years of date, and I want to add just one row across two dates. For example for Kid=A and Kid2=15, I have data on Jan 1st and then on Jan 10th; So I add only one row between them.

Comment: @user3582968 I am not sure I understand what you want: You don't want to include all dates anymore, you want just one row between dates? Which date would this row be?

Comment: HI... So my current data is 29M with 160,000 unique combinations of Ids(kid and kid2). So I am calculating change across days on variable "sums"; So that's why I wanted to add filler rows based on dates but what matters is just one row for any missing dates. For example between Jan 1 and Jan 10 , I just need one record in between to show difference from Jan 1 to and then to Jan 10. This will help in keeping datasize to reasonable levels..So anytime if the next date is not consecutive, add one row with next date .

Comment: @CarlosCinelli : Hi..the date will be the first missing one. so in same example Jan 2..So I was using lead function to calculate difference and if diff>1 then insert a row. But I am trying with small sample so I can create the full data. But I want to optimize and just add one row only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way this can be done.

```
#sample data
df<-data.frame(
    date = c("01/01/2012", "01/10/2012", "01/03/2012", "01/01/2012"),
    kid = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
    kid2 = c(12, 15, 10, 10),
    sums = c(123,100, 900, 100)
)

#borrow from @Carlos
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"),
    as.Date("01/31/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"), by="day"),
    format="%m/%d/%Y"
)

#now create factors
df$date<-factor(df$date, levels=dates)
df$kid2<-factor(df$kid2)
df$kk<-interaction(df$kid, df$kid2, drop=T)

#so we can use xtab
dd <- as.data.frame(xtabs(sums~date+kk, df))

#optionally, split back apart kid/kid2
dd <- cbind(dd, 
   `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind,
        strsplit(as.character(dd$kk),".", fixed=T)
    ),c("kid","kid2"))
)
```